# How to refresh outlook profile signature settings in registry

Tags: outlook, registry, vsto, signature

I have made an outlook plug in that downloads a new signature and creates the registry keys for the profile to set the new and reply signature.  Is it possible to get outlook to pick up these new registry settings without restarting?

Edit:
Just to clarify the settings I am applying in the registry are in the sub keys of "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office[OFFICE VERSION]\Outlook\Profiles\Outlook\9375CFF0413111d3B88A00104B2A6676" which hold the profile settings.

Answer (score 1):

No - any changes to Outlook settings in the registry are never read until Outlook starts.